# Using the same script for dealing with different triggers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers

I have a scene with multiple triggers and a Player with collider. My idea is to have one script to deal with all interactions between triggers and Player collider. I thought that using the same script to different GameObjects would be enough but this thing doesn't work properly. While working with one trigger I need to change one GameObject attached to this trigger but the other GameObjects with this script are changing as well.

One more detail about script is that I have two types of triggers: one is for GameObjects that need some input from user, some doesn't need it. I check it by checking two fields `firstChoiceText` and `secondChoiceText`. And if they are empty, the interaction with GameObject doesn't need any choice from the player. Otherwise, I show a plane with two option and change the text of this options using `firstChoiceTextfield` and `secondChoiceTextfield`.

So the main idea of script is that when the Player enter the trigger the script activates E key of keyboard. And if we press the E button and if this interaction wasn't done yet, we go further. We check the type of trigger and if we need to make a choice, we activate so called `choiceMode` of `PlayerScript`. PlayerScript is just a script for movements of the player, and we need `choiceMode` just to use W and S keys to select the choice. We make our choice and return to usual movement of the player. If we don't need to make a choice we just do some action and mark the trigger as `isDone`.

Everything works great with one trigger but when I use several triggers and GameObjects with `InteractionScript`, all this triggers are mixed up. While working with one trigger I accidentally change the other script. And I don't quite understand how to separate this scripts from each other.

Can anybody give me some piece of advice?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InteractionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField]
  private GameObject buttonE;
  [SerializeField]
  private GameObject choiceMenu;
  [SerializeField]
  private PlayerScript ps;

  private int choiceNum = 0;
  [SerializeField]
  private Transform choicePoint;
  [SerializeField]
  private Text firstChoiceTextfield;
  [SerializeField]
  private Text secondChoiceTextfield;

  [SerializeField]
  private string firstChoiceText;
  [SerializeField]
  private string secondChoiceText;
  [SerializeField]
  private bool enteredMe;
  [SerializeField]
  private bool isDone;

  void OnTriggerEnter2D() {
    if (!isDone) {
      enteredMe = true;
      buttonE.SetActive(true);
      Debug.Log("++");
    }
  }

  void OnTriggerExit2D() {
    if (!isDone) {
      buttonE.SetActive(false);
      enteredMe = false;
    }
  }

  void Update() {
    if (!isDone) {
      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && buttonE.activeSelf && enteredMe) {
        if (firstChoiceText != "" && secondChoiceText != "") {
          choiceMenu.SetActive(true);
          buttonE.SetActive(false);
          ps.choiceMode = true;
          Debug.Log("with choice");
        } else {
          Debug.Log("without choice");
          //Action
          buttonE.SetActive(false);
          isDone = true;
        }
      }
    }

    if (ps.choiceMode) {
      firstChoiceTextfield.text = firstChoiceText;
      secondChoiceTextfield.text = secondChoiceText;

      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) {
        choiceNum += 1;
      }

      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) {
        choiceNum -= 1;
      }

      if (choiceNum > 1) {
        choiceNum = 0;
      } else if (choiceNum < 0) {
        choiceNum = 1;
      }

      if (choiceNum == 0) {
        choicePoint.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 24f, 0f);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)) {
          Debug.Log("choice1");
          choiceMenu.SetActive(false);
          isDone = true;
          enteredMe = false;
          ps.choiceMode = false;
        }
      } else if (choiceNum == 1) {
        choicePoint.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, -21.5f, 0f);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)) {
          Debug.Log("choice2");
          choiceMenu.SetActive(false);
          isDone = true;
          enteredMe = false;
          ps.choiceMode = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So is the script you have shown on the moving player or on all the Trigger Objects?

Comment: @pixlhero InteractionScript is on all Trigger Objects

Comment: it might be easier to centralize the logic on the player in one script. there you can sort out what should happen if for example you touch multiple objects. it's also a bit easier to debug, cause there is a single point where the trigger logic happens.

Comment: @pixlhero so I just should put everything on one script and use OnCollider enter to detect triggers?

Comment: yeah. I think it'll make it easier to coordinate the trigger objects.